# Change / remove twitter fabric login webview text in android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am implementing twitter fabric to login using twitter account in my app. All is working well but in login webview of twitter, there is text like, -

> **Authorise Created by Fabric for (username)-projects:(package name) on android to use your account.**

Can I change/remove this text?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.